# Can' read JSON element in Swift

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I'm using Swift 3.0 and cannot seem to parse this JSON response.

```
{
    "books": [{
        "name": "NAME",
        "key": "Key"
    }],
    "count": 1
}
```

Here is what I am using

```
let booksData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]

if let bookCount = booksData["count"] as? String {
    print("found")
}
else {
    print("Not Found")
}
```

I must be missing something really obvious here. I'm trying to read count before reading the array of books.

Comment: Why are you casting the JSON object to a string array? Also, what error, exactly are you getting?

Comment: @SumnerEvans since the JSON is key value pairs of type String:Any. bookCount is just not being found. Its found if books does not exists, but not found if books does exists.

Comment: Please include the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if let bookCount = booksData["count"] as? NSNumber {
    print("found")
} else {
    print("Not Found")
}
```

In your JSON data, see `"count": 1`. The value `1` is a JSON number, which is converted to `NSNumber` with `JSONSerialization`. And `as?` casting from `NSNumber` to `String` always fails.

Comment: I just figured it out and was heading back to SO to write how much an idiot I am. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @HPatel, Maybe relaxing for half an hour before posting questions would be a good practice. Good luck for you and for your apps.

Answer (score 0):

`if let bookCount = bookData` should be `if let bookCount = booksData`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the question; edited the question appropriately